# What is wrong in this python script?

Tags: python

I want to ask for help in writing or editing my script.

This is what my script should do:

- I have some config file (right on screen)
- and I want to change string "backup_source" but change only after
  "=" (for something like /home/forBackup), and this changing should be by user (I think with input).

I have my script but this is not working. I don't know python very well, so I am asking for help from this community =)

UPGRADE >>

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
path = '/Users/test/test3.conf'
name1 = input('what setting you to change? ')
value1 = input('what you want to change in this setting: ')


def set_parametrs(name1, value1):
    with open(path) as f:
        current_config = f.read().splitlines()
    for i, option in enumerate(current_config):
        if option.split("=")[0].strip() == name1 and option.split("=")[1].split()[0].lower() == g:
            current_config[i] = '%s = %s' % (name1, value1)
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(current_config))
        f.close()


def check_dir():
    if os.path.isdir(value1):
        print('we have this dir')
        return True
    else:
        print('we dont have this dir')
        return False


g = [
    'backup_destination_automake'
    'backup_destination_prefix'
    'backup_schedule'
    'backup_keep_on_errors'
    'method_rsync_sudo'
    'method_rsync_differential'
    'method_verify'
    'method_device_eject'
    'report_remote_uri_down'
    'report_stdout'
    'report_stdout_on_errors'
    'report_email'
    'report_email_on_errors'
    'report_email_rcpt'
    'report_html'
    'report_html_on_errors'
    'report_html_logo'
]


d = {
    'backup_source': check_dir,
    'backup_destination': check_dir,
    'backup_exclude': check_dir
}


def check_yes_no():
    for key, value in d.items():
        if name1 == key:
            print('this parametr is valid')
            return True
    else:
        print('this parametr is invalid')
    return False


if name1 and value1 and d[name1] == check_dir():
    set_parametrs(name1, value1)
else:
    print("bad")
```

[if i want change with yes\no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsZX8.png)
[if i want change way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6ozx.png)

Comment: Where do you call that function? add `set_option(name1, value)` after all the code

Comment: `.startswith(name1 + '=')` is never true if there is anything between `name1` and the `=` and in your file there is whitespace before every `=`. I suggest you use an actual parser for the config format.

Comment: Nothing is wrong.. mayne comments in russian.. may limit the readability to russian speakers

Comment: I don't see where the set_option() function is called? in main?

Comment: @eyllanesc i'm sorry, what you mean Where? in concole python3 pit.py

Comment: no, on line 23 of the file

Comment: @eyllanesc you mean write set_option(name1, value1) on line 23

Comment: yesssssssssssss

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah yeah xD forgot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startswith(name1 + '=')
```

You're ignoring the fact that there are space characters between the name and equals sign.

The .strip() function only removes space and other special characters from the beginning and the end of the string.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
path = '/home/artem/.synbak/rsync/test.conf'
name1 = 'backup_source'  # имя параметра
value1 = input('what you want backup:')  # то что задает пользователь


def set_option(name1, value1):
    with open(path) as f:
        current_config = f.read().splitlines()
    for i, option in enumerate(current_config):
        if  option.split("=")[0].strip() == name1:
            current_config[i] = '%s=%s' % (name1, value1)
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(current_config))
        f.close()
```

**EDIT**
A solution if this were to be used more as a cli tool.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--input", '-i', required=True)
parser.add_argument("--output", '-o', required=True)
parser.add_argument("--argument", required=True)
parser.add_argument("--value", help='what you want backup:', required=True)

# testing
args = parser.parse_args(
"-i /home/artem/.synbak/rsync/test.conf -o /home/artem/.synbak/rsync/test.conf --argument backup_source --value your_value".split())


# development
# args = parser.parse_args()


def set_option(args):
    new_config = []
    with open(args.input) as f:
        for option in f:
            value = f"{args.argument}={args.value}" if option.split("=")[0].strip() == args.argument else option
            new_config.append(value)
    with open(args.output, 'w') as f:
        print(*new_config, sep="\n", file=f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_option(args)
```

Usage:

```
>python your_script.py -i conf.cfg -o new_conf.cfg --argument backup_source --value /my/new/backup/dir
```

**Just the input handling case**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
path = '/home/artem/.synbak/rsync/test.conf'
name1 = 'backup_source'  # имя параметра
while True:
    value1 = input('what you want backup:')  # то что задает пользователь
    if value1:
        break
    else:
        print("Bad input")
```

**UPDATE 2018/12/20 Solution**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

YES_NO_PARAMETER_NAMES = [
    'backup_destination_automake',
    'backup_destination_prefix',
    'backup_schedule',
    'backup_keep_on_errors',
    'method_rsync_sudo',
    'method_rsync_differential',
    'method_verify',
    'method_device_eject',
    'report_remote_uri_down',
    'report_stdout',
    'report_stdout_on_errors',
    'report_email',
    'report_email_on_errors',
    'report_email_rcpt',
    'report_html',
    'report_html_on_errors',
    'report_html_logo'
]

DIRECTORY_PARAMETERS = [
    'backup_source',
    'backup_destination',
    'backup_exclude'
]


def set_parametrs(line, name1, value1):
    """
    >>> set_parametrs("# Something random comment","my_field","my_value")
    '# Something random comment'
    >>> set_parametrs("my_field  = other_value # Something random comment","my_field","my_value")
    'my_field = my_value'

    :param line:
    :param name1:
    :param value1:
    :return:
    """
    option = line.split("=")[0].strip()
    if option == name1:
        return '%s = %s' % (name1, value1)
    return line


def check_dir(my_dir):
    if os.path.isdir(my_dir):
        print(f'we have <{my_dir}> dir')
        return True
    else:
        print(f'we dont have <{my_dir}> dir')
        return False


def check_yes_no(line):
    """
    >>> check_yes_no("report_html = yes")
    this parametr is valid
    True
    >>> check_yes_no("some_other_param = yes")

    >>> check_yes_no("report_html = wrong")
    this parametr is invalid
    False

    :param line:
    :return:
    """
    option, sep, value = line.partition("=")
    if sep:
        if option.strip() in YES_NO_PARAMETER_NAMES:
            if value.split()[0].lower().strip() in ['yes', 'no']:
                print('this parametr is valid')
                return True
            else:
                print('this parametr is invalid')
                return False
    return None  # None is always returned if there's nothing at the end of the function


def check_dirs_for_keys(line):
    option, sep, value = line.partition("=")
    if option in DIRECTORY_PARAMETERS:
        value, sep, comment = value.partition("#")
        value = value.strip()
        if " " in value:
            for directory in value.split():
                check_dir(directory)
        else:
            check_dir(value)


path = '/Users/test/test3.conf'
name1 = input('what setting you to change? ')
value1 = input('what you want to change in this setting: ')

data = []
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(set_parametrs(line, name1, value1))
        check_yes_no(line)
        check_dirs_for_keys(line)

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    print(*data, sep="\n", file=f)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185524/discussion-on-answer-by-ebro42-what-wrong-in-this-script-on-python).

Answer (score 3):

The trivial answer is that you don't seem to be calling that function from anywhere, but I assume that's being handled externally.

More to the point is probably misunderstanding how `strip` works.

```
with open(path) as f:
    options = f.read().splitlines()  # this is f.readlines(), but that's fine

for i, option in enumerate(options):
    if option.strip().startswith(name1 + '='):  # <-------
```

`str.strip` only removes whitespace from the beginning and end of strings, not anywhere in the middle. Your line that contains `name1` is:

```
backup_source                        = /bin /boot /etc /home /lib* /opt /root /sbin /srv /usr /var
```

which means your conditional should be:

```
if option.strip().startswith(name1 + "                        ="):
```

or, more reasonably, you should parse the key/values.

```
if option.startswith("#") or not option.strip():
    continue  # skip comments and blank lines

key, valuestr = map(str.strip, option.split('='))  # split on equals and strip both ends

if key == name1:
    # do whatever it is you need to do.
```

Comment: N.B. regex could also be used effectively here, which might be cheaper than string splitting and stripping `pat = re.compile(rf"^\s*#.*|^(?P<key>\S+)\s*=\s*(?P<values>(?:\S+\s*)+)$")`